# Simplest GUI frontend to demo GCP Vertex AutomML Image Classification

Tags: vertex, google-cloud-automl, automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai, gpc

I've built a GCP Vertex AutoML Image Classification model and deployed to endpoint. It works great from the Deploy and Test tab. What's the simplest way to let others without access to the project try it via a GUI? The required functionality is to upload an image from your computer and let the model output the predicted class.

Is there an existing tool I can use (has to be a GUI, not command line)? If not what's the simplest way to build such frontend?

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the [python code from samples](https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/blob/main/samples/snippets/prediction_service/predict_image_classification_sample.py) to run this. Although it's not a GUI frontend but you can quickly engineer one around it.

the usage is:

```
predict_image_classification_sample(
    project: str,
    endpoint_id: str,
    filename: str,
    location: str = "us-central1",
    api_endpoint: str = "us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com",
)
```